# Java program freezes until socket connection is made

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I am making a simple telnet implementation in Java from ground up.
I have already made a simple socket connection between client and server work. My problem is just that the whole server application freezes when it is waiting for a connection - even though i am running it in a seperate thread. Is there any (preferably) simple way to get around this?

Thread starter snippet:

```
    worker slave = new worker();
    Thread slaveThread = new Thread(slave);
    slaveThread.run();
```

Thread snippet:

public class worker implements Runnable{

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        ServerSocket srv = new ServerSocket(1337);
        System.out.println("Thread is running!");

        Socket clientSocket = srv.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection made.");
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Failed.");

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Java Newbie

Comment: But are you running the separate thread correctly?  Your problem suggests not.  Without code though, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Let me guess, you 'start the thread' by calling `run()`?

Comment: @Ishtar, I was thinking the exact same thing.

Comment: @both: me too! We'll see if he responds.

Comment: @Mike Great minds think alike ;)

Comment: Yes i start the thread with calling run()

Comment: The issue is solved now. Thanks alot for your input!

Comment: I bumped Ishtar's rep as he was the first to suggest run().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes i start the thread with calling run()

Although Thread implements Runnable, you aren't supposed to call `run()`. You should call [Thread.start()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29), which calls `run()` in the new thread. If you call `run()` directly, the **current** thread is the one that executes it, not the Thread you created.

Comment: Should i place Thread.Start() in the thread itself before run() or in the "main" file? (I have two seperate files, main and worker), or should i use it as "SlaveThread.start(); instead of SlaveThread.run();?

Comment: @Java Newbie, call `start` on the `Thread` object you create. Don't call it from within `run()`. i.e., `slaveThread.start()` instead of `slaveThread.run()`.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Thank you Mike. I will approve your answer :-).